# HLSL DXGI_FORMAT_A8_UNORM Texture - dark colors appear less opaque than white

Tags: textures, directx, hlsl, alpha

I am trying to render a `DXGI_FORMAT_A8_UNORM` texture (precisely, a font bitmap) in multiple colors by specifying the color per vertex and then apply the alpha value from the sampled texture in the pixel shader. When white is specified as the vertex color, the rendered texture looks as expected, however with darker colors the texture looks "thinned" or less opaque, as displayed in the attached picture. 
These are the used shaders, with `fontSampler` using `D3D11_FILTER_MIN_MAG_MIP_POINT` as filter:

```
Texture2D shaderTexture : register(t0);
SamplerState fontSampler : register(s0);

struct VS_INPUT
{
    float2 pos : POSITION;
    float4 col : COLOR;
    float2 tex : TEXCOORD0;
};

struct VS_OUTPUT
{
    float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
    float4 col : COLOR;
    float2 tex : TEXCOORD0;
};

VS_OUTPUT VS(VS_INPUT input)
{
    VS_OUTPUT output;
    output.pos = mul(projection, float4(input.pos.xy, 0.f, 1.f));
    output.col = input.col;
    output.tex = input.tex;
    return output;
}

float4 PS(VS_OUTPUT input) : SV_TARGET
{
    input.col.a = shaderTexture.Sample(fontSampler, input.tex).a;
    return input.col;
}
```

[image: colored alpha texture]

Comment: What blending mode are you using? BTW, you may want to look at ``SpriteFont`` in the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK).

Comment: I don't observe an error here. Are you sure it's not an optical illusion due to the eye's  varying levels of response / perception of contrast in dark ranges versus bright ranges?

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn 
`BlendEnable = true;
SrcBlend = D3D11_BLEND_SRC_ALPHA;
DestBlend = D3D11_BLEND_INV_SRC_ALPHA;
BlendOp = D3D11_BLEND_OP_ADD;
SrcBlendAlpha = D3D11_BLEND_INV_SRC_ALPHA;
DestBlendAlpha = D3D11_BLEND_ZERO;
BlendOpAlpha = D3D11_BLEND_OP_ADD;
RenderTargetWriteMask = D3D11_COLOR_WRITE_ENABLE_ALL;`
and blend factor `{ 0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f }`;

Comment: @DMGregory I'm positive that there is a subtle difference

Comment: As a temporary workaround, i have changed the pixel shader to incorporate the grayscale value:
`static const float3 conv = { 0.3, 0.59, 0.11 };

float4 PSFONT(VS_OUTPUT input) : SV_TARGET
{
 float gray = mul(conv, input.col.rgb);
 input.col.a = shaderTexture.Sample(fontSampler, input.tex).a * (1.25-gray/4);
 return input.col;
}`

Comment: You've probably noticed that code doesn't format nicely in comments. Instead, code that helps explain your problem should be added to the question by editing it. Code that helps you solve the problem should be posted as an Answer.